# Finding the value of a sum of two Hecke eigenvalues

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I did some computations but I am stuck in finding the exression of the sum
$$\lambda_f(n^2)+\lambda_f(n)^2 $$ in terms of $\lambda_f(n),$ where $f$ is a modular form for the full modular group. Any help is appreciated.